# Displaying html from a php string

Tags: php, html

How can i get the following string to actually display the html AS html. I want to see a clickable link that the user can click as well instead of just html.

`$_SESSION['errortext'] = 'You have successfully logged in. <a href="">Click Here</a> or wait to be redirected.';`

I did a search and couldnt find anything on it. Seems "Outputing HTML from a php string" is somewhat ambiguous as i was getting all manner of results in google.

Ok, so apparantly somewhere down the line i am actually escaping the HTML, my bad.

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['errortext']`?

Comment: Your search likely came up with ambiguous results because "echo" is literally the first thing you ever learn about PHP - it's almost 100% of the "Hello World" for PHP.

Comment: if this question is worth an upvote, y'all have really low standards for good questions.

Comment: yeah, i was escaping the html like a baddy somewhere else. Sorry y'all

Comment: When I tested this, it displayed the html correctly
$_SESSION['errortext'] = 'You have successfully logged in. <a href="">Click Here</a> or wait to be redirected.';
  echo $_SESSION['errortext'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $_SESSION['errortext'];
```

Comment: also ensure you have session_start(); at the very top of your php page

Answer (score 0):

change the quotes and try.

```
$_SESSION['errortext'] = "You have successfully logged in. <a href=\"\">Click Here</a> or wait to be redirected.";
```